# Save Output of Caffe Transform to Image

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, caffe

Sorry if this is a bit naive, but I'm trying to learn a bit more about the image types that go along with Caffe models, and in disecting some code, I'm struggling to figure out a core concept.

In this example project, I have some code like so;

```
caffe_transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': nsfw_net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
caffe_transformer.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))  # move image channels to outermost
caffe_transformer.set_mean('data', np.array([104, 117, 123]))  # subtract the dataset-mean value in each channel
caffe_transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)  # rescale from [0, 1] to [0, 255]
caffe_transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2, 1, 0))  # swap channels from RGB to BGR
```

This references a function which performs the following preprocessing;

```
img_data_rs = resize_image(pimg, sz=(256, 256))
    image = caffe.io.load_image(StringIO(img_data_rs))

    H, W, _ = image.shape
    _, _, h, w = caffe_net.blobs['data'].data.shape
    h_off = max((H - h) / 2, 0)
    w_off = max((W - w) / 2, 0)
    crop = image[h_off:h_off + h, w_off:w_off + w, :]
    transformed_image = caffe_transformer.preprocess('data', crop)
    transformed_image.shape = (1,) + transformed_image.shape
```

(where pimg is a passed image; said image could be an unknown size)

What I would like to do is save out the *transformed_image* to a file, a png or jpg, so I could understand what exactly is happening here.

I attempted the following;

```
img = Image.fromarray(transformed_image, 'RGB')
img.save('myImage.jpg')
```

This led me to;

**ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.**

Is what I'm attempting a possibility based on the above?  Thank you!